# How can I create preview of long video in short gif or other format by skipping numbers of frames?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5-video

First of all let me explain my requirement here. I have to show list of videos in one web page. I am using asp.net mvc 4 as UI part. Basically we have requirement when user mouse hovers or clicks on the video thumbnail box we have to show preview of that video. Suppose my video is of 10 minute then I will show that full video in 10 seconds as preview by skipping numbers of frames.

If user will click on the title of video, they will see full video. Is there any jquery or any other tool available for this?

Comment: I would say you would need some server side processing of the videos for making the "gifs"/Teaser videos. Its not possible with jQuery.

Comment: @Webbanditten Thanks, I understand this but I need to create Gif but it should be like if video is of 10 minute, gif should will show preview/highlight in 10 seconds. Is this possible?